# HTML select box, how do I move/copy selected options from one <select> to another

Tags: jquery, select, css-selectors

I can't make this little script work: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NpTzR/)

I want to pass selected options from a Multiple Select to another using buttons.
I think there is a problem with jQuery selector when trying to select all "`option:selected`".

HTML :

```
<div>
    <select id='canselect_code' name='canselect_code' multiple>
        <option value='1'>toto</option>
        <option value='2'>titi</option>
    </select>
    <input type='button' id='btnRight_code' value='  >  ' />
    <br>
    <input type='button' id='btnLeft_code' value='  <  ' />
    <select id='isselect_code' name='isselect_code' multiple>
        <option value='3'>tata</option>
        <option value='4'>tutu</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('[id^=\"btnRight\"]').click(function (e) {

    var selectedOpts = $(this).prev('select option:selected');

    if (selectedOpts.length === 0) {
        alert('Nothing to move.');
        e.preventDefault();
    } else {
        $(this).next('select').append($(selectedOpts).clone());
        $(selectedOpts).remove();
    }

});

$('[id^=\"btnLeft\"]').click(function (e) {

    var selectedOpts = $(this).next('select option:selected');

    if (selectedOpts.length === 0) {
        alert('Nothing to move.');
        e.preventDefault();
    } else {
        $(this).prev('select').append($(selectedOpts).clone());
        $(selectedOpts).remove();
    }

});
```

The "_code" mention is in my app a dynamic code, that's why i use `[^selector]`
 instead direct id selectors like `(#)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I managed to get it working rewriting all your code into neat one liner.

[JSFiddle: (**MOVE** option to the other element) - http://jsfiddle.net/GJJQw/](http://jsfiddle.net/GJJQw/)
[JSFiddle: (**COPY** option to the other element) - http://jsfiddle.net/dEE7A/](http://jsfiddle.net/dEE7A/)

The below code `COPIES` the select elements into the other select box.

```
$('[id^=\"btnRight\"]').click(function (e) {
    $(this).prev('select').find('option:selected').clone().appendTo('#isselect_code');
});

$('[id^=\"btnLeft\"]').click(function (e) {
    $(this).next('select').find('option:selected').clone().appendTo('#canselect_code');
});
```

If you wanted to `MOVE` (ie delete from one, and add to the other).. Use this:

```
$('[id^=\"btnRight\"]').click(function (e) {
    $(this).prev('select').find('option:selected').remove().appendTo('#isselect_code');
});

$('[id^=\"btnLeft\"]').click(function (e) {
    $(this).next('select').find('option:selected').remove().appendTo('#canselect_code');
});
```

---

**Heres a small step by step breakdown:**

```
// the button that was clicked
$(this)

// .next('select') = get the next <select> element
.next('select').

// .find('option:selected') = get all the selected options
.find('option:selected')

// .remove() [or .clone()] = Remove or clone the found options
.remove() // OR .clone()

// .appendTo('#id-of-element') = Append the found elements to the other select box
.appendTo('#canselect_code');
```

So by changing the `.remove()` to `.clone()` you will COPY the option to the other select, otherwise `remove()` will remove it from this select element, and append it to the other.

Comment: Yes, wi just wanted to test it on my app before accepting answer. I'll post the answer that fits well my code ;)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this updated fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/NpTzR/1/

There were two issues in your code,

1st, The code to get the selected options was wrong. The following is how it should have been.

`var selectedOpts = $(this).prev('select').find('option:selected');`

2nd, The code to fetch the select to which to move the options was wrong. I couldn't think of a way to fetch the select without using a css selector. In my opinion doing it this way conveys the intent clearly.

Modified markup (added a css class to each select):

```
<div>
    <select id='canselect_code' name='canselect_code' multiple class='fl js-rightSelect'>
        <option value='1'>toto</option>
        <option value='2'>titi</option>
    </select>
    <input type='button' id='btnRight_code' value='  >  ' />
    <br>
    <input type='button' id='btnLeft_code' value='  <  ' />
    <select id='isselect_code' name='isselect_code' multiple class='fr js-leftSelect'>
        <option value='3'>tata</option>
        <option value='4'>tutu</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Modified js

```
$('[id^=\"btnRight\"]').click(function (e) {

    var $selectedOpts = $(this).prev('select').find('option:selected'),
        $nextSelect = $(this).siblings('.js-leftSelect');

    if ($selectedOpts.length === 0) {
        alert('Nothing to move.');
        e.preventDefault();
    } else {
        $nextSelect.append($selectedOpts.clone());
        $selectedOpts.remove();
    }

});

$('[id^=\"btnLeft\"]').click(function (e) {

    var $selectedOpts = $(this).next('select').find('option:selected'),
        $prevSelect = $(this).siblings('.js-rightSelect');

    if ($selectedOpts.length === 0) {
        alert('Nothing to move.');
        e.preventDefault();
    } else {
        $prevSelect.append($selectedOpts.clone());
        $selectedOpts.remove();
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for quick/quality answers !

This works perfectly in my app : http://jsfiddle.net/GJJQw/1/

I just modify the appendTo selector, because i don't know the id/name of the next select, and i have many of them on the same webform (yes i know, this is a bad and ugly form anyway ...)

JS :

```
    $('[id^=\"btnRight\"]').click(function (e) {
        $(this).prev('select').find('option:selected').remove().appendTo($(this).nextAll('select'));
    });

    $('[id^=\"btnLeft\"]').click(function (e) {
        $(this).next('select').find('option:selected').remove().appendTo($(this).prevAll('select'));
    });
```

Demonic oneliner 3:-)

Thanks again 
Eric

Answer (score 0):

Try this javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btnRight_code").click(function(){
    $("#canselect_code option:selected").remove().appendTo($("#isselect_code"));
})
  $("#btnLeft_code").click(function(){
    $("#isselect_code option:selected").remove().appendTo($("#canselect_code"));
})
});
```